# ./droidgap:4:in `require': no such file to load

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to get PhoneGap working.  I've hit a hurdle getting started.

I've downloaded version 0.9.1.  I've been following the instructions at http://phonegap.pbworks.com/Getting-started-with-Android-PhoneGap-in-Eclipse

Using MacOS 10.5.8.  Android SDK is already installed and working with Eclipse.

My .bash_profile file looks like this:-

```
$PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin

export PATH=${PATH}:/Applications/android-sdk-mac_86/tools
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/phonegap-android/bin
```

(and I restarted my terminal window to make it take effect)

I've tried the following command:-

```
cd /Applications/phonegap-android/bin

ruby ./droidgap /Applications/android-sdk-mac_86 HelloPhoneGap  com.myidentity.android /Users/myidentity/Documents/workspace/HelloPhoneGap/assets/www /Users/myidentity/Desktop
```

...and I get the following error:-

> ./droidgap:4:in `require': no such file to load -- /Applications/phonegap-android/bin/lib/generate.rb (LoadError)
>       from ./droidgap:4

Why?

Comment: if you look in that directory "/Applications/phonegap-android/bin/lib/" is the file there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this issue as well, move droidgap up one level into the phonegap base directory.

Answer (score 1):

Or, you should mention the complete path:

```
export PATH=$path: /Applications/phonegap-android/bin/**droidgap**
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across such issues too. go to https://github.com/jonathanstark/phonegap-android, search the generate.rb  file in the lib folder there, download it, then you are good to go.